# PyMySQL variable using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES in one database

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm looking to automate creating a database and user from user input with the pymysql module.

I'm looking to grant all privileges to the newly created user in one database:

```
cur.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON %s.* to %s@%s IDENTIFIED BY %s", (DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_PASS))
```

I get the below error.

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test26'.* to 'test26'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test26'' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use query parameters to escape database or table names. Those use backticks as escape character, not quotes:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name`.* ...
```

So for the database and server part you need to use string manipulaton, which means you need to ensure the data is properly sanitized, e.g. by allowing only alphanumeric characters as database names.